# Scoped match routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is it possible to set scope for match routings.

I have tried this:

```
scope "/admin" do 
  match ':controller/:action/:id' 
emd
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
scope "/admin" do 
  match ':controller/:action/:id', :to => 'home#index', :via => 'get'
end
```

You have to match something TO something else… The :via method definition isn't mandatory.

**EDIT**

You may also try

```
scope "/admin" do 
  match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))' 
end
```

Comment: It seems that this doesn't work and it is impossible to combine scope with match.

Comment: I was wrong, it works. It even works using namespace instead of scope. Thank you Yannis you save my day.